# Assigning instance names to array Objects: ActionScript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, flash-cs5

I'll just start by saying that I am a bit new to programming, and I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I have a timer running in my application that at every interval, creates an a new instance of a MovieClip called blueBall.Here is my code:

```
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 350;
var newBlue:mc_BlueBall = new mc_BlueBall  ;
newBlue.x = randomX;
newBlue.y = -20;

for(var i:Number = 0;i < blueArray.length; i++)
{
newBlue.name = "newBlue" + i;
}

blueArray.push(newBlue);
addChild(newBlue);

}
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 350;

var newBlue:mc_BlueBall = new mc_BlueBall  ;
newBlue.x = randomX;
newBlue.y = -20;

for(var i:Number = 0;i < blueArray.length; i++)
{
newBlue.name = "newBlue" + i;
}

blueArray.push(newBlue);
addChild(newBlue);

}
```

My question is: How do I make it so that each newly created object in the array has it's own hitTestObject Event? I want to make it so that if the if the user's icon touches one of the newBlue objects, that newBlue object with be removed, and the score will go up a point.

Thanks!

Comment: You should change the name of the question, it does not reflect the real question.

Answer (score 1):

this is my first time answering a question here but I hope I can help! Assuming you have a timer for your main game loop, you should try something like this once per frame:

```
//For each blue ball in the array
for(var i:int = 0; i < blueArray.length; i++) {
    //If it touches the player
    if(blueArray[i].hitTestObject(thePlayerMC)) {
        //Increment the score
        score++;
        //Remove from stage and array
        removeChild(blueArray[i]);
        blueArray.splice(i, 1); //<-At index i, remove 1 element
        //Decrement i since we just pulled it out of the array and don't want to skip the next array item
        i--;
    }
}
```

This is sort of the quick and dirty solution, but highly effective and commonly used.